# Select all elements of a listview in pywinauto using send_message

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, win32com, pywinauto

Need help to select all elements of a listview using send_message. I want  this to work in RDP disconnected mode and hence using pywinauto's send_message api.
My code

```
from pywinauto import win32defines
app = Application().connect(path = pathToAppEXE)
lvitem = win32structures.LVITEMW()
lvitem.mask = win32defines.LVIF_STATE
lvitem.state = 1
lvitem.stateMask = win32defines.LVIS_SELECTED
app.window_(title_re = "Net Position.*").ListView.send_message(win32defines.LVM_SETITEMSTATE,-1,lvitem)
```

It does nothing. Maybe I am not getting the lvm flags correctly. Need assistance to fix the code.

Comment: Already gone through the remote execution guide. That itself is pretty clear as I am trying to use low level methods independent of whether I had gone through the remote execution guide or not.

Answer (score 0):

Method `.get_item(...)` (see [docs](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.common_controls.html#pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ListViewWrapper.get_item)) should return [_listview_item](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.common_controls.html#pywinauto.controls.common_controls._listview_item) object with some available methods: some of them don't involve real click.

Maybe [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html) is also useful.

Comment: I have already gone through remote execution guide and clearly stated that I am trying to solve for RDP. I dont see your answer is relevant. I have already highlighted the issue that I am trying to use send_message to the listview and its not working. Thats the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Did you follow this link? https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html It's in the Remote Execution Guide. Other guys tell me it's working. So you don't have to use `send_message` or other workarounds in this case.

Comment: Also `_listview_item` object uses `send_message` inside. I'd like to avoid writing low level code which is already written in pywinauto. The answer is relevant, but you need some efforts to look into mentioned API.

Comment: Don't mind. Already gone through the remote execution guide. That itself is pretty clear as I am trying to use low level methods independent of whether I had gone through the remote execution guide or not.Also pls Understand the problem from my point of view. The problem is that some methods in pywinauto use low level code and some do not. For example button click is not working in RDP and so I use send_message to click the button. So I want to have consistency in my code that either I use send_message everywhere or you add support for low level code for all operations in next version default.